# Como usar uma função de um arquivo Vue em outro arquivo Vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Eu estou fazendo um jogo usando o **Vue.js** que **eu comecei a aprender 2 dias atrás** e eu cheguei em um problema que pode comprometer todo o meu jogo.

Basicamente o que eu quero fazer é criar um arquivo **borda2.vue** com uma fatia do meu jogo em HTML que contém 3 funções, `GotejarA() GotejarB() e GotejarD()`.

```
<div id="reagir">
     <div>
       <h3>Gotejar Anti-A</h3>
       <button class="btns" id="gotejarAA" @click="GotejarA"></button>
     </div>
     <div>
       <h3>Gotejar Anti-B</h3>
       <button class="btns" id="gotejarAB" @click="GotejarB"></button>
     </div>
     <div>
       <h3>Gotejar Anti-D</h3>
       <button class="btns" id="gotejarAD" @click="GotejarD"></button>
     </div>
</div>
```

Feito isso, eu exportei esse arquivo com as 3 funções como *CBorda2*

```
export default {
  name: "CBorda2"
};
```

Até ai tudo bem, o problema agora é o seguinte, em outro arquivo **divididor.vue** eu importei o *CBorda2* e utilizei ele como uma tag personalizada

```
<template>
    <CBorda2 />
</template>

<script>
import CBorda2 from "./borda2.vue";


export default {
  name: "CDivididor",
  components: {
    CBorda2
  },
};
</script>
```

Eu quero criar um methods no **divididor.vue** referente as 3 funções do arquivo **borda2.vue**

```
<script>
import CBorda2 from "./borda2.vue";


export default {
  name: "CDivididor",
  components: {
    CBorda2
  },
   methods: {
     GotejarA() {
      alert("Pingou!")
     }
  },
};
</script>
```

Isso não funcionou e eu não sei como resolver, tem algum jeito de realizar isso? Eu estou usando o Vue3 CLI e desesperado estou.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

O problema que esta tendo é uma questão de diferença em trabalhar com JS e Vue que é eventos e funções, no Vue você não sobe uma função de um filho pro pai, você sobe um evento conforme escrito aqui: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events

Então a questão é como subir um evento? você primeiro tem que fazer com que seus `GotejarX.vue` emitam eles.

```html
<button class="btns" id="gotejarAA" @click="$emit('gotejarA')"></button>
```

E no `Divididor.vue` quando for usar os `GotejarX.vue` você vai usar um callback quando receber tal evento.

```
<GotejarX @gotejar-a="funcaoGotejarDivid"></button>
```

Answer (score -3):

Cada componente age de forma separada. O Vue exporta o seu próprio componente Vue e não as funções dele. Você está usando os métodos no componente "CBorda2", porém declarou seus métodos no componente "CDivididor". O que acontece é que o componente "CBorda2" não encontra estas funções e retorna um erro no console.
Para solucionar você precisa declarar as funções no componente que irá usá-las.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Não use imagens para publicar código. Código deve ser publicado como texto.